# Jison/Bison Get line number of a token in a grammar

Tags: parsing, bison, jison

I am wondering how shall I get the line number of a token inside a grammar. Suppose I have the following grammar:

```
S : expr MINUS expr { $$ = $1 -$3; }
  ;
```

How to get the line number for MINUS token? 
I am not using the lexer inside jison but rather pass it from a lex file by overriding the lexer:

```
parser.lexer = {
  lex: function() {
    var token = "MINUS";
    parser.lexer.yytext = "...";
    parser.lexer.yylineno = xx;
    return token;
  }
}
```

I realized that I could call `yylineno` but what if different tokens in a grammar have different line numbers and I only want line number of a specific token in the jison file.
Maybe something like `$1.yylineno`?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jison gives you access to locations using the `@` notation. See the "Tracking Locations" section [here](http://zaach.github.io/jison/docs/). The line number of your minus symbol above would be `@2.first_line`.

Then it is up to your lexer to provide the information that Jison expects.